# OpenStack error when converting a glance image to a cinder volume

Tags: cloud, openstack, centos7, openstack-glance

`/var/log/cinder/volume.log` shows the following error when converting a glance-registered QCOW2 image to a cinder volume.

`local variable 'tmp' referenced before assignment failed to copy image to volume`

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary conversion directory and grant the cinder user and group ownership:

```
mkdir /images/conversion
chown cinder:cinder /images/conversion
```

Modify the `image_conversion_dir` directive in `/etc/cinder/cinder.conf`:

```
image_conversion_dir=/images/conversion
```

Restart the cinder volume service:

```
systemctl restart openstack-cinder-volume.service target.service
```